# Problems with waiters AWS PHP SDK3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to change instance type but since I have updated to SDK3 this script fails. I don't know what I'm doing wrong with waiters.

```
            $client = new Ec2Client(self::getCredentials());

            $client->stopInstances(array(
                'InstanceIds' => $instanceIds,
            ));

            $client->waitUntil('stopped', [
                'InstanceId' => $instanceId,
            ]);

           $client->ModifyInstanceAttribute(array(
                'InstanceId' => $instanceId,
                'Attribute' => 'instanceType',
                'Value' => $instanceType
            ));

        $client->startInstances(array(
            'InstanceIds' => $instanceIds,
        ));

        $client->waitUntil('running', [
            'InstanceId' => $instanceId,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. 
The problem was that InstanceId param was wrong... You have to use an array of instaces Ids.

```php
                $client->waitUntil('InstanceStopped', [
                    'InstanceIds' => array($instanceId),
                ]);

                $client->waitUntil('InstanceRunning', [
                'InstanceIds' => array($instanceId),
                ]);
```